# Topological demonstration about directions in a straight line

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

A straight line has, in the traditional sense of the term, two directions; we can mark a starting point and from it we observe two directions, or in other words, to reach any point on a straight line we can do it only in two directions.

I heard that there is a topological demonstration that it is not possible to algebraically construct a straight line with more than two directions.
Do any of you know that demonstration and where can I find it?"

Comment: What do you mean by "algebraically construct"? What's a direction (to you)?

Comment: Here's what comes to (my) mind: A direction on _the_ (there's only one up to homeomorphism, namely $\mathbb{R}$) line is something like an orientation of the line as a manifold. For any manifold there are either exactly 0 or 2 orientations, and the line clearly has at least one, whence exactly two, so there are two directions on the line Q.E.D. You can find an exposition to the theory of orientations in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology in the section on Poincaré duality.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, Ben!